# How to update the state of an element with the values from another state element?

Tags: reactjs

I have an input field called `Description` in a form where the words in the input field get updated through an API request similar to autocomplete. Visually it works as intended, when the user types something then they can select which word is appropriate, then the selected word is inputted into the input field.

`description` contains the state for when a user types anything into the input field and the state with the autocomplete suggestion is `selectedDescription` which gets updated using an API request.

```
// contains the value from the API request that is used to update the input field with
const [selectedDescription, setSelectedDescription] = useState(undefined);
// contains the state from all the input fields in the form 
const { name, date, title, time, description } = state;

<Input
  fluid
  placeholder="Description"
  value={selectedDescription || description}
  onChange={(e) => {
    if (
      selectedDescription === undefined ||
      selectedDescription !== e.currentTarget.value
    ) {
      dispatch({
        type: "field",
        field: "description",
        value: e.currentTarget.value,
      });
    }
  }}
/>
```

But in state it is not updated as `selectedDescription` is not included in the form's initial state and I do not know how to take the state from `selectedDescription` and update `description` with it.

```
// Initial State
const initialState = {
  name: "",
  date: "",
  title: "",
  time: "",
  description: "",
};

function formReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "submit": {
      return {
        ...state,
      };
    }
    case "field": {
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.field]: action.value,
      };
    }
    case "reset": {
      return {
        initialState,
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}



// button for submitting the data
<Button
  type="button"
  onClick={() => {
    dispatch({ type: "submit" });
  }}
>
 Submit
</Button>
```

Comment: From what I gather, you want to set `state.description` the same as `selectedDescription` after the user selects a description ?

Comment: Yes when the user selects an autocompleted word that word would be `selectedDescription`, from there the selectedDescription would need to replace the value in `description`in order to show up in the state.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the reducer for that, I think.

```
  case "submit": {
    return {
      ...state,
    };

  case "field":  {
    return {
      ...state,
      description: action.value
    };
  
  default:
    return {
    ...state
   };

}
```

Comment: It does not work, the same issue still persists and the other fields do not work now.

Comment: Have you put your code up somewhere so that I could look at the full source code ? It is a bit difficult to analyse how you've set up your actions/reducers by looking at a tiny portion of the actual code.

Comment: I added in the entire reducer function and I cannot share the full source code as I am not the owner of the repository. If you need anything else from it let me know.